# Why are the app labels missing in "all apps" list?

Tags: applications, settings

My "all apps" list doesn't show the app names and I have no idea how I turned it off. Because I'm using a theme I have a really hard time figuring out what icons belong to which apps.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

How do I turn the labels/names back on for the apps in the "all apps" list?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! It might help if you [edit] your question and include device name, Android version, and the launcher used – without that it's hard to tell for us as well.

Comment: @Ariella Which launcher and theme are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** - In your homescreen, press and hold on a free space to get to this menu

[image: Homescreen]

**2** - Click on the up arrow to enter advanced settings and you'll be presented with a screen like this

[image]

**3** - **Scroll down** till you get to **Drawer Settings**(Do not confuse it with Homescreen Settings).   In the **Icon Labels** options change it to **Show**

[image: Drawer Settings]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer (with pictures!) On how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager that you're using Cyanogenmod or CyanogenOS with a custom theme. The fourth icon in first row belongs to AudioFX, quite common in Cyanogenmod.

If that's the case then go to home screen, press Menu button. You would see options such as Wallpapers, Widgets and more. Swipe up that dialog and change **Icon labels** under **Drawer Settings** from **Hide** to **Show**.

That should take care of the issue.

Comment: That was it. I'm still new to android so I wasn't even aware this was a launcher setting? I got this with my phone so I never installed it myself. I thought it was a phone setting, hence the lack of information with my post. Thanks a bunch!